# How to get all words and their frequency from a webpage?

Tags: java, php, perl, web-crawler

I have to get all words and their frequency from a web page and the other pages which are linked. Will I have to use any web crawler for that? Any simple open source solution?

Comment: An [SEO Analyzer](http://www.seoworkers.com/tools/analyzer.html) may be of some help to you.

Comment: There are far too many ways to parse a web page and collect words from it to be confined to a single answer.

Comment: Does not deserve these downvotes. Both compound questions are well answerable. The latter one is subjective, yet the parent can easily pick and promote the most appropriate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Open amplify should work perfectly for you.

http://www.openamplify.com/

Answer (score 1):

[httrack](http://httrack.com)'s `%I` (create searchable index) option does exactly that.

The [documentation page](http://httrack.com/html/fcguide.html) explains this about half-way down, sorry, no deeplink available. Jump to the sentence fragment

> Still in testing, this option asks the engine to

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you might get the content of the web page (using [file_get_content()](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) or curl), then [strip_tags()](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) and [str_word_count()](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php)

Comment: Ok, that's fine, but how can I browse all the pages of a site. Will I use regular expressions to extract URLs of web pages and then get them with the same procedure?

Comment: Yes, you'd need to use a crawler to pull all linked web pages